AspectJAdviceParameterNameDiscoverer not able to discover aspect parameters - Spring boot 3 - Java 17
I am migrating my application from spring boot 2 to spring boot 3 and java from 10 to 17.
I am having an aspect in my application which was working fine with current version of spring boot 2.2.1 whereas while migrating the application to spring boot to 3.2.1 it is throwing AmbiguousBindingException while binding the parameters using maybeBindThisOrTargetOrArgsFromPointcutExpression method.
Tried with updating the maven complier plugin with parameters as true but no luck.
I understand that in latest spring boot there is no support for LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer. Also in previous version the parameter were discovered using this only and it never went to AspectJAdviceParameterNameDiscoverer for processing.
aspectjweaver : 1.9.8
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <parameters>true</parameters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

Aspect :
@Aspect
@Component
public class TestAspect {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestAspect .class);
    private final TestExceptionHandler testExceptionHandler;

    public TestAspect (@Autowired TestExceptionHandler testExceptionHandler) {
        this.testExceptionHandler= testExceptionHandler;
    }

    @Around("execution(* com.csharma.test.practise.TestGenericProcess.execute(..)) && target(process) && args(context)")
    public void afterThrow(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, TestGenericProcess process, Context context) throws Throwable {
        try {
            joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable var5) {
          //
        }
    }
}


You need a newer version of the AspectJ weaver. If you are using Spring Boot and have the spring boot starter parent you don't need to reconfiger the compiler plugin that is already done. Spring Boot already manages the version of AspectJ for you remove the version tag you are using and let Sprng Boot manage the compatible version.

If after following Marten's advice you still have problems, please publish a full, minimal reproducer on GitHub. In general, please learn how to ask a question on SO and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Thank you.

@M.Deinum Thank you for reply, it doesn't worked after updating the AspectJ version as well. Previously the parameters were getting resolved using LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer discoverer and these are the parameters which were resolved by this class.
LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer  - ["joinPoint", "process", "context"]

And while using AspectJAdviceParameterNameDiscoverer for resolve the aspect parameters I am getting below in argument list before reaching to resolve the same by maybeBindThisOrTargetOrArgsFromPointcutExpression method.
AspectJAdviceParameterNameDiscoverer  -  ["thisJoinPoint", null, null]
and because of this it is throwing exception as remaining unbounded argument is greater than 1 (numberOfRemainingUnboundArguments > 1) in this case it is 2.
Thanking you in anticipation

@csharma, was anything unclear about the term MCVE? did you follow the link and read the page? Please, like I said, proivide a GitHub project. Developers want to analyse and debug code, not try to interpret ambiguous textual descriptions of same. You cannot expect anyone to create a new project from scratch, inserting your code snippets and making educated guesses about the rest.

Since the aspect which was causing the issue was coming from some other library and once we compiled that library code with command line parameters '-parameters' and reimported the project that issue got resolved. Thanks
